# Canny can't get full complete contour in python

Tags: python, canny-operator

[image]

I use canny in python.
My image value only 0 and 1.

So my code be like this

```
canny = cv2.Canny(obj_map, 0, 1)
plt.imshow(canny)
plt.show()
```

Then got this result.

[image]